# Error: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am getting following error while running a java program which uses solrj jar file.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/admin.html. Reason:
<pre>    HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Following is the java code from which error is coming:

```
    private static long addResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, SolrServerException, IOException
    {

        System.out.println("Inside addResultSet");

//      while(rs.next())
//      {
//          System.out.println(rs.getString("id")+" "+rs.getString("name")+" "+rs.getString("principal"));
//      }

        long count = 0;
        int innerCount = 0;
        Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
        ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
        int numColumns = rsm.getColumnCount();
        String[] colNames = new String[numColumns + 1];

        /**
         * JDBC numbers the columns starting at 1, so the normal java convention
         * of starting at zero won't work.
         */
        for (int i = 1; i < (numColumns + 1); i++)
        {
            colNames[i] = rsm.getColumnName(i);
            /**
             * If there are fields that you want to handle manually, check for
             * them here and change that entry in colNames to null. This will
             * cause the loop in the next section to skip that database column.
             */
            // //Example:
            // if (rsm.getColumnName(i) == "db_id")
            // {
            // colNames[i] = null;
            // }
        }

        while (rs.next())
        {
            count++;
            innerCount++;

            SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

            /**
             * At this point, take care of manual document field assignments for
             * which you previously assigned the colNames entry to null.
             */
            // //Example:
            // doc.addField("solr_db_id", rs.getLong("db_id"));

            for (int j = 1; j < (numColumns + 1); j++)
            {
                if (colNames[j] != null)
                {
                    Object f;
                    switch (rsm.getColumnType(j))
                    {
                        case Types.BIGINT:
                        {
                            f = rs.getLong(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Types.INTEGER:
                        {
                            f = rs.getInt(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Types.DATE:
                        {
                            f = rs.getDate(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Types.FLOAT:
                        {
                            f = rs.getFloat(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Types.DOUBLE:
                        {
                            f = rs.getDouble(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Types.TIME:
                        {
                            f = rs.getDate(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Types.BOOLEAN:
                        {
                            f = rs.getBoolean(j);
                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                        {
                            f = rs.getString(j);
                        }
                    }
                    doc.addField(colNames[j], f);
                }
            }
            docs.add(doc);

            /**
             * When we reach fetchSize, index the documents and reset the inner
             * counter.
             */
            if (innerCount == fetchSize)
            {
                solrCore.add(docs);
                docs.clear();
                innerCount = 0;
            }
        }

        /**
         * If the outer loop ended before the inner loop reset, index the
         * remaining documents.
         */
        if (innerCount != 0)
        {
            solrCore.add(docs);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Error is coming from line solrCode.add(docs);

The exact error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/orca: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Don't know what `solrCore` (not `solrCode`) does, but it's likely trying to POST to the wrong URL.

Comment: @Andreas I was trying to POST to URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/orca
where orca is my core name. 
However, if i am trying with http://localhost:8983/solr/orca, it is showing following error: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/orca: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you add id field to your docuement

Comment: @Ramzy yeah I added the id field but since it was coming from SQL, it was coming as ID. I just converted ID to lower case and it worked!